# How to order icon next to a span in HTML with CSS?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am trying to do something like a verification on contact form, e.g if email does not contain "@" and "." show icon of red X and if the conditions are done show green check mark. I need answer on 2 questions: 1. How to align the icon next to the span and the 2. How to center the form in the middle of the screen? I tried with display:flex, many other floats, positions, aligns and every solution I found in the internet, but I anything had success in setting the icon between different tags and centering the form in the middle of the screen but the only one thing I came to is: [link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XVRwI.jpg)

```js
< script type = "text/javascript" >
  $(document).ready(function() {
    $('.submit').click(function(event) {
      console.log('Clicked button')
      var name = $('.name').val()
      var email = $('.email').val()
      var phone = $('.phone').val()
      var message = $('.message').val()
      var statusElm = $('.status')
      statusElm.empty()

      if (email.length > 5 && email.includes('@') && email.includes('.')) {
        statusElm.append('<i style="color: green; font-size:2.3em;" class="fas fa-check"></i>')
      } else {
        event.preventDefault()
        statusElm.append('<i style="color: red; font-size:2.3em;" class="fas fa-times"></i>')
      }

      if (phone.length > 7 && phone.legth < 14) {
        statusElm.append('<i style="color: green; font-size:2.3em;" class="fas fa-check"></i>')
      } else {
        event.preventDefault()
        statusElm.append('<i style="color: red; font-size:2.3em;" class="fas fa-times"></i>')
      }

      if (message.length > 20) {
        statusElm.append('<i style="color: green; font-size:2.3em;" class="fas fa-check"></i>')
      } else {
        event.preventDefault()
        statusElm.append('<i style="color: red; font-size:2.3em;" class="fas fa-times"></i>')
      }
    })
  }) <
  /script>
```

```html
<div class="mail " id="mail">
  <div class="container">
    <h3 class="w3l_head w3l_head1">Contact Me</h3>
    <p class="w3ls_head_para w3ls_head_para1">send Me a message</p>
    <div class="w3_mail_grids">
      <form action="https://formspree.io/ntodorov301@gmail.com" method="POST" class="justify-content-center">
        <div class="col-md-6 w3_agile_mail_grid">
          <span class="input input--ichiro"><input
           class="input__field input__field--ichiro" type="text" name="name"
           id="input-25" placeholder=" " > 
           <label class="input__label input__label--ichiro" for="input-25">
            <span class="input__label-content input__label-content--ichiro">Your
             Name</span>
          </label>
          </span>
          <a class="status" name="status"></a> <span class="input input--ichiro"> <input
           class="input__field input__field--ichiro email" type="email" name="Email"
           id="input-26" placeholder=" " > <label
           class="input__label input__label--ichiro" for="input-26">
            <span class="input__label-content input__label-content--ichiro">Your
             Email</span>
          </label>
          </span> <span class="input input--ichiro"> <input
           class="input__field input__field--ichiro phone" type="text" name="phone"
           id="input-27" placeholder=" " > <label
           class="input__label input__label--ichiro" for="input-27">
            <span class="input__label-content input__label-content--ichiro">Your
             Phone Number</span>
          </label>
          </span>

        </div>
        <div class="col-md-6 w3_agile_mail_grid">
          <textarea class="message" name="message" placeholder="Your Message"></textarea>
          <input type="submit" value="Submit" class="submit">
        </div>
        <div class="clearfix"></div>
      </form>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Can you provide a demo or the link which generates the image output?

Comment: https://imgur.com/t4qeFx1/

Comment: https://imgur.com/o8zEfcp

Comment: I mean with your current code, it is hard for us to look into your problem. If you can reproduce your localhost to a public version, maybe we can help.

Comment: I can't :( If you tell me a free way

Comment: You can use this app: https://stackblitz.com/

Comment: What is CSS framework you use?

Comment: Bootstrap and stackblitz.com is for Angular

Comment: Why you don't want to use [Bootstrap styles](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.3/components/forms/#custom-styles) to format and align the validation icons?

Comment: I don't know this Form from Bootstrap is not working properly with my JS.

Comment: Thats why I am asking here

Comment: You could implement custom validation logic using JavaScript to apply `.is-valid` or `.is-invalid` classes to the form controls. It's easier than framework rules overriding 

Comment: Can you give me a hint where to set this properties? best regards I think I understood but can't apply it

Answer (score 0):

The Bootstrap is alredy used on the page. Thus, I recommend you to apply [validation](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.3/components/forms/#validation) feature of the framework instead of creation of custom CSS rules. You could use `.is-valid` and `.is-invalid` styles for the controls or [constraint validation API](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/form-control-infrastructure.html#the-constraint-validation-api) within custom validation methods.

The following example will help you to get started. I don't want to post too much code, therefore my form contains a single control.

```js
document.getElementById('emailField')
  .addEventListener('input', function(e) {
    this.classList.remove('is-valid', 'is-invalid')
    if (!isValidEmail(this.value))
      this.classList.add('is-invalid');
    else
      this.classList.add('is-valid');
  }, false);

document.getElementById('myForm')
  .addEventListener('submit', function(e) {
    checkEmail(document.getElementById('emailField'));
    if (!this.checkValidity()) {
      event.preventDefault();
      event.stopPropagation();
    }
    this.classList.add('was-validated');
  }, false);

function checkEmail(control) {
  if (!isValidEmail(control.value)) {
    control.setCustomValidity('The e-mail is invalid.');
    console.log(control.validationMessage);
  } else {
    control.setCustomValidity('');
  }
}

function isValidEmail(email) {
  return /^[\w!#$%&'*+-\/=\?^_`{|}~](\.?[\w!#$%&'*+-\/=\?^_`{|}~])*@gmail\.com$/i.test(email);
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">


<div class="container">
  <form id="myForm" novalidate>
    <div class="form-group">
      <label for="emailField">Email address</label>
      <input type="email" class="form-control" id="emailField" aria-describedby="emailHelp" placeholder="Enter email">
      <small class="valid-feedback">The e-mail address is valid!</small>
      <small class="invalid-feedback">The e-mail address is invalid.</small>
      <small id="emailHelp" class="form-text text-muted">Only <a href="https://www.google.com/gmail/">Gmail</a> is supported</small>
    </div>
    <button class="btn btn-primary" type="submit">Send</button>
  </form>
</div>
```

The snippet uses `.is-invalid` and `.is-valid` classes to indicate validation result while user is inputing e-mail address. In the submit event handler the constraint validation API is used. The forms allows to send only address of Gmail. If you will try to use another domain it throws an error.